# How to extract href contents in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have HTML code as:
"
        1.

```
<a href="/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_tt">The Shawshank Redemption</a>
<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">(1994)</span>
```

"

How do I extract the  "The Shawshank Redemption" from 'a' tag using Beautiful soup?

Comment: can you provide the html structure in the question? or at least the url that contains the html you want to parse

Answer (score 1):

A simple search would have given you

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<a href="/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_tt">The Shawshank Redemption</a>
<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">(1994)</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.a.text)
print(soup.find('a').text)
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(a.text)

print(soup.a.get_text())
print(soup.find('a').get_text())
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(a.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

st = r"""<a href="/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_tt">The Shawshank Redemption</a>
<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">(1994)</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(st, 'html5lib')
a = soup.find_all('a')
a[0].text
```